# Is there a way to break this Unity 2d code into seperate methods

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, 2d

I am trying to use onscreen buttons to go up and down a ladder the current code works just fine with the W and S keys, but I'm not quite sure how to put the code into seperate methods so the touch can access it.

I was researching accessing the colliders on the player and the ladder from a separate script but they said it couldn't be done. I also tried assigning the Keycode to a separate variable inside a method then assigning this method to the onscreen keys but that didn't work.

```
public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, speed);
    }
    else if (other.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, -speed);
    }
    else{
        other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough details to work from but, unless I misunderstood you completely, if all you want to do is to move the player using screen touch input instead of the keyboard input then the simplest way to handle it without changing too much in your working code would be to simply assign Boolean variables to the input conditions and check for them instead of the keyboard input inside the function you shared.

So, for example, the function would look something like:

```
    public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player" && UpKeyPressed)
        {
            other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, speed);
        }
        else if (other.tag == "Player" && DownKeyPressed)
        {
            other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, -speed);
        }
        else{
            other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 1);
        }
    }
```

Where UpKeyPressed and DownKeyPressed are Boolean variables which can be set to true/false when you touch the screen based keys or whatever is the UI for the touch based input.

Comment: Okay so I took your advice and used the Boolean variables and set them to true when the button is clicked it seems to work fine on one ladder in the scene but not on the other.

Comment: If it's working for one ladder then the same logic will work on the other one. You will have to check if the OnTriggerStay2D function is even getting called on that other ladder or not, or if any of the conditional statements in the function are failing for this function for that ladder, or if the collider component is missing from that ladder object etc. You know, good ol' fashion debugging. :)

Comment: Well I think in theory it should be the same I first created a prefab of the original then used the prefab I even put back the W and S keys in the code. The W and S keys work for both ladders but the Touch I works for one even though it's a prefab

Comment: From your comment, it seems that there is a mismatch between the scripts attached to the two ladders. The modified one with the Boolean variables won't work for keyboard input anymore because we replaced the Input.GetKey() check with the Boolean one. Since it is still working for the other ladder, you may want to compare the scripts attached to the two objects.

Comment: No that's the thing the second ladder is basically a clone of the first one because I made a prefab then deleted the original so basically I am cloning the first ladder over and over again

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit vague. It might help providing a more detailed scenario. However, refactoring this into a method so something else can access it does not seem that complicated, unless I misunderstand you.

```
public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    RigidBody2D rigidBody2d =  other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    if (other.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        SetVelocity(rigidBody2d, 0, speed);
    }
    else if (other.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        SetVelocity(rigidBody2d, 0, -speed);
    }
    else
    {
        SetVelocity(rigidBody2d, 0, 1f);
    }
}

// public, assuming you want to access this from somewhere else. 
public void SetVelocity(Rigidbody2D rigidBody, float horizontalSpeed, float verticalSpeed)
{
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalSpeed, verticalSpeed);
}
```

Comment: I would basically like to climb a laddering using touch controls so right now the real problem for me is checking if the collider on the player and the ladder are touching so he can climb.